# How to list all graph vertex attributes in R?

Tags: r, igraph

I am using the [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/attributes.html) package in R.

I would like to associate some data with each vertex, e.g. by adding id and description attributes to each.  The attributes are determined at runtime.  I have a couple of related questions about how to set and get this data.

To set a vertex's id I use (where `g` is a graph):

```
> set.vertex.attribute(g,'id',1,'first_id') # etc
```

I expected to be able to read the attributes back with:

```
> get.vertex.attribute(g,'id',1)
```

But this returns NULL. Am I doing something wrong?

Further, the function with the `get.vertex.attribute` call does not have access to the list of attribute names. How can I extract the attribute names from the graph `g`?

Finally, I want to set/get the values of the attributes from/into a named list.  Is there a simple way to do that without looping through every vertex and attribute and applying `set.`- or `get.vertex.attribute`?

thanks!

Comment: Had the same experience. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like you have to assign the results of `set.vertex.attribute` back to `g` like so:

```
g <- graph.data.frame(data.frame(one=1:2,two=2:3))
g <- set.vertex.attribute(g,'id',1,'first_id')
get.vertex.attribute(g,'id',1)
#[1] "first_id"
```

As the help at `?get.vertex.attribute` says:

> graph: The graph object to work on. Note that the original graph is
>             never modified, a new graph object is returned instead; if
>             you don't assign it to a variable your modifications will be
>             lost! See examples below.

Further, from the same help file there is...

> list.graph.attributes, list.vertex.attributes and list.edge.attributes
>   return a character vector, the names of the attributes present.

```
list.vertex.attributes(g)
#[1] "name" "id"
```

From a quick look there doesn't seem to be a simple function to write in/out the vertex attributes *en masse*. You can concoct something like this though:

```
lapply(list.vertex.attributes(g),function(x) get.vertex.attribute(g,x))
#[[1]]
#[1] "1" "2" "3"
# 
#[[2]]
#[1] "first_id" NA         NA
```

Comment: It must be a new feature, but the following command is very convenient for extracting all vertex attribute data:    get.data.frame()

Answer (score 7):

Use the following syntax to assign vertex attributes in-place:

```
> V(g)[1]$id <- "first_id"
> V(g)[1]$id
[1] "aaa"
```

This syntax also allows you to retrieve or set a vertex attribute for all the vertices; just omit the indexing:

```
> V(g)$id <- c("aa", "bb", "cc")
```

Comment: This works well, but can you help me with this?: I only have the attribute name in a variable, e.g. idName = "id".  Although `V(g)$id` works well, `V(g)[[idName]]` gives me the error `Error in V(g)[[idName]] : subscript out of bounds`.  How should I reference it using idName? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not an expert in R so I don't know whether there is any simpler way, but after some experimentation I found this to work: `eval(parse(text=paste("V(g)$", varname, sep="")))`. This basically creates a string containing the expression to evaluate, parses it and then calls `eval` to evaluate the expression.

Comment: No, you can't do this with `V(g)$`. It is actually the same with plain lists, you cannot do `list$element` if `element` is a variable name, either. In this case you need to use `get.vertex.attribute` and `set.vertex.attribute`.